# Guzzle with Xdebug cannot find his function

Tags: php, xdebug, guzzle

I am using Xdebug to coverage Laravel PHP project that uses Guzzle.

Composer config:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
```

My PHP is v7.1.33 in a bitnami (based on Debian) docker.

Without Xdebug everything is OK but when I add Xdebug it starts showing Guzzle exception:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp_idn_uri_convert() in /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:220

Actually, `_idn_uri_convert` is defined in `src/functions.php` and without the Xdebug Guzzle worked well.

Xdebug config is:

```
zend_extension="/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable = On
xdebug.auto_trace=Off
xdebug.collect_params=Off
xdebug.collect_return=Off
xdebug.trace_output_dir=/tmp/midi/trace
```

I try to also use these config lines, but nothing changes:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [the corresponding issue on GitHub](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2511).

It should not happen really, but there are a few people facing this error. Please try clear you cache, remove `vendor` folder and reinstall all the deps. If nothing helps, then provide your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` in the issue above.

If you use Laravel Installer, please update it.